# Is 'theris' a 3rd person plural possessive pronoun?

Tags: grammar, pronouns

I saw a grammar chart earlier today stating 'theris' is a third person plural possessive pronoun. I've never seen this word used.

Comment: I'd suggest you completely ignore that grammar chart.

Comment: If they’ll show you theirs, you can show them yours.

Comment: Surley taht gramamr chrat contanis mnay tyops

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is almost certainly quoting a typo.

Answer (score 3):

That almost certainly was a typo for "theirs".

Answer (score 0):

There's no such word. Theirs, not theris.